# bash separate parameters with specific delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I am searching for a command, that separates all given parameters with a specific delimiter, and outputs them quoted.

Example (delimiter is set to be a colon `:`):

```
somecommand "this is" "a" test
```

should output

```
"this is":"a":"test"
```

---

> I'm aware that the shell interprets the "" quotes before passing the parameters to the command. So what the command should actually do is to print out every given parameter in quotes and separate all these with a colon.

I'm also **not** seeking for a bash-only solution, but for the most elegant solution.
It is very easy to just loop over an array of these elements and do that, but the problem is that I have to use this inside a `gnu makefile` which only allows *single line shell commands* and uses `sh` instead of `bash`.

So the simpler the better.

Comment: "It is very easy to just loop over" - so why don't you do it?

Comment: Because in gnu makefile I can only have single line statements, and additionally they will only be executed in a shell and not a bash.

Comment: Launch an external command. Can be in any scripting language.

Comment: And which one exactly do you suggest me to use? (This was the question)

Comment: By "outputs them quoted" -- what exactly is the goal for that quoting? Is it intended to be `eval`-safe quoting? How is it supposed to handle literal quote characters inside the data? What constitutes correct quoting depends on what software is going to be parsing a given string, and I don't believe this question specifies that.

Comment: BTW, you *do* realize that you can control which shell make uses from your makefile, right?

Comment: And extend the shell command over multiple lines as well.

Comment: Would it be OK to invoke Ruby or Perl for this job? In this case, it would be trivial.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes i do. But the goal was to use makefile's defaults.

Comment: To be very, very clear -- the quoting done here isn't `eval`-safe (nor would it be simply substituting single-quotes either). If you have `'$(rm -rf ~)'` in an argument, that'll be emitted in double quotes where it's executed on evaluation; whereas `$'\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` would be a version able to escape single quotes, etc. If you want to generate eval-safe quoting, that's a job for `printf %q` (whereas generating valid JSON quoting is a job for `jq`, generating Python-safe quoting is a job for `python -c 'import sys; print repr(sys.argv[1])'`, etc).

Comment: This matter of there only *being* such a thing as valid quoting once the parser consuming the syntax is known is part of why I'm little wary of the question as currently asked, specifying only "quoted" with not a word more of detail.

Comment: (CSV quoting, to pick another oddball, requires literal quote characters to be doubled if found inside the literal data, just as many other formats do with backslash-escapes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wow - thanks for the extensive information! I didn't know that such a thing like %q exists in printf. You're right with your assumption: I do want to generate eval-safe quoting. I actually didn't express myself clear enough - sorry for that. The intention was to add better support for "non-standard" filenames in `gnu make`. As you probably now, even simple spaces are a big pain in the ass. It 's possible to use them by escaping with a '\' - but all makefile-specific functions (execpt wildcard) will break then. So i need to replace all internal functions with my bash-alternatives.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By the way, at the time I wrote this question I didn't realize that it all was THAT bad concerning makefiles support for uncommon filenames. I just want to harden my build system to be prepared for those odd cases. And I the only way around I can imagine is by handling all filnames in bash commands only. Or do you know a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Alas, the gritty details of make are outside my expertise. Which is funny -- half my job experience is wearing some variety of build-engineer hat, but back when it was at an OS distributor I mostly spent time dealing with autoconf and RPM (and porting software written in C to be able to cross-compile for our target platforms), and it's mostly been Java (well, JVM; currently Clojure) shops since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
somecommand () {
    printf '"%s"\n' "$@" | paste -s -d :
}
```

Use `printf` to add the quotes and print every entry on a separate line, then use `paste` with the `-s` ("serial") option and a colon as the delimiter.

Can be called like this:

```
$ somecommand "this is" "a" test
"this is":"a":"test"
```

Comment: Hmm. You could almost use `printf ':"%s"'` and just trim the first character -- or put the `:` on the end and trim the last. If the shell were bash rather than sh (as used by makefiles by default), one could avoid not just pipelines but even subshells that way.

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I though of, thanks. @CharlesDuffy This is possible indeed, as the resulting command doesn't care about a trailing one. But what is this feature of printf called? Never heard of it.

Comment: @bricklore, ...support for repeating the format string if extra arguments are left over? I'm not sure that it has a shorter name. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
apply_delimiter () { 
    (( $# )) || return
    local res
    printf -v res '"%s":' "$@"
    printf '%s\n' "${res%:}"
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ apply_delimiter hello world "how are you"
"hello":"world":"how are you"
```

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in a number of the comments, a simple "*loop-over*" approach, looping over each of the strings passed as arguments is a fairly straight-forward way to approach it:

```
delimit_colon() {
    local first=1
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [ "$first" -eq 1 ]; then
            printf "%s" "$i"
            first=0
        else
            printf ":%s" "$i"
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
}
```

Which when combined with a short test script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

delimit_colon() {
    local first=1
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [ "$first" -eq 1 ]; then
            printf "%s" "$i"
            first=0
        else
            printf ":%s" "$i"
        fi
    done
    printf "\n"
}

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate input
    printf "error: insufficient input\n"
    exit 1
}

delimit_colon "$@"

exit 0
```

**Test Input/Output**

```
$ bash delimitargs.sh "this is" "a" test
this is:a:test
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using the z-shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# this is "somecommand"
echo '"'${(j_":"_)@}'"'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have them in an array already, you can use this command

```
MYARRAY=("this is" "a" "test")
joined_string=$(IFS=:; echo "$(MYARRAY[*])")
echo $joined_string
```

Setting the IFS (internal field separator) will be the character separator. Using echo on the array will display the array using the newly set IFS. Putting those commands in $() will put the output of the echo into joined_string.

Comment: To make this properly applicable to the question, I'd suggest `$*` rather than `${MYARRAY[*]}` (since it's referring specifically to parameters). Also, you might want to quote the expansion being used as an argument to `echo`.