# Parameter Substitution shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

How do I use parameter substitution in shell?
I have a string like :123 abc xyz
If I want to substitute it in this form 123,abc,xyz 
How do I do it?

Comment: what shell ? linux ? windows ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash separate parameters with specific delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801908/bash-separate-parameters-with-specific-delimiter)

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam it should be in linux .

Comment: You have a three answer, please check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
echo ":123 abc xyz" | sed 's/^.//' | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

The first `sed` removes the first char in the line (:) and the second `sed` replaces all spaces with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this ?

```
[root@xxx sync_tools]# echo "123 abc xyz" | awk '{OFS=",";$1=$1}1'
123,abc,xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you free, which shell you can use for this on Linux? With `zsh`, parameter substitution is easy. Assuming that your string is stored into variable PAR, i.e.

```
PAR=":123 abc xyz"
```

you can get the desired replacement by

```
echo ${${PAR:1}// /,}
```

The `:1` drops the first character, the `//` means *global substitution*, and the rest simply replaces all spaces by comma.